# Adding hidden_field through facebook signup authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, facebook, devise, omniauth

I would like to add a hidden field to my facebook signup authentication. Im using `omniauth`, `devise`. I need to find a way to add a field when clicking the facebook signup button to determine if the user is a basic user or a member. On the `link_to` could i add another field and would this get passed to a certain controller or model?

- last time i tried making a form with the url being the link to `omniauth(:facebook)` adding a hidden_field `user_type` with the value of "member".

below is the example of what I tried, even though my user table is not being updated with `member` or 'basic-user'.

```rails
<%= form_for(resource, :url => user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)) do |h| %>  

  <%= h.hidden_field :user_type, value: 'member' %>
  <%= h.submit "Sign Up With Facebook", class:"btn btn-primary2" %>

 <% end %>
```

**This is my user.rb model**

```rails
def self.from_omniauth(auth)

 # anonymous_username = "NewUser#{User.last.id + 1}"
 generated_password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]

 user = User.where(:email => auth.info.email).first

 if user
  return user
else
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.confirmed_at = Time.now
    user.fullname = auth.info.name
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = generated_password
    if auth.info.image.present?
     avatar_url = process_uri(auth.info.image)
     user.avatar = URI.parse(avatar_url)
   end
 end

 user.update_attributes username: "NewUser#{user.id}"

  end
end
```

- where can i find `user_type` data that i just made with the `hidden field`?
- should i use `resource` in my form like my non-facebook custom forms for devise or should I use `@user`?

If getting data from a hidden field is impossible then what is another way I can do this? Maybe I could use a session but i don't really understand how devise sessions work or where i can edit them to include this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a form.  Since your field is hidden so you aren't expecting users to change it, then you can just pass a link to authorize with facebook and add the params to your URL.

```
<%= link_to "Sign Up With Facebook", omniauth_authorize_path(:user, :facebook, user_type: 'member') %>
```

Then on the backside, when they send the data back, it's available in the auth hash.

In your model you can use `auth.options` to get the data back out again:

```
auth.params[:user_type]
```

Comment: i got this error `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass` This is a way better solution though! i didnt know i could do that! as for the error its cause of a class?

Comment: odd.. I do this all the time.  In your omniauth callback controller where you call the omniauth method in your model, try calling a raise / inspect on `request.env["omniauth.params"]` -- see if you can find where  and how its stored.

Comment: `Completed 500 Internal Server Error RuntimeError ({"user_type"=>"member"}):`  is the error i got when i put `raise request.env["omniauth.params"].inspect`

Comment: if it's in the auth hash then you should be able to get to it in your model.  You can try a raise in your model, make sure the data is still with your `auth` when it's passed.

Comment: updated the answer everything works like a charm! thank you for the lesson!